# Proper way to use try/catch

Tags: java, try-catch

I've been working on getting this working for a while, so I'm looking for help. In my following code my exception is not printing my custom error, rather it just crashes and I don't know why. Any *help* would be appreciated.

```
try {
        {
            JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
            btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter     your name");

                    answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is 2 + 3?");
                    userAnswer = Integer.parseInt(answer);
                    try {
                        if (userAnswer == 5) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good!!");
                            score = score + awarded;
                        }

                        else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "Not Even Close!");
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        System.out.println("enter a number");
                    }
                    answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is 2 x 8?");
                    userAnswer = Integer.parseInt(answer);
                    try {
                        if (userAnswer == 16) {
                            score = score + awarded;
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Super!!");

                        }

                        else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "Not Even Close!");
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        System.out.println("enter a number");
                    }

                    answer = JOptionPane
                            .showInputDialog("What is 144 / 12?");
                    userAnswer = Integer.parseInt(answer);
                    try {
                        if (userAnswer == 12) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "Excellent!!");
                            score = score + awarded;
                        }

                        else {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                    "Not Even Close!");
                        }
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        System.out.println("enter a number");
                    }

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "Thanks for playing " + name
                            + " Your score is " + score);

                }
            });
            btnStart.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                    MathJFrame.class
                    .getResource("/com/sun/java/swing/plaf/windows/icons/Computer.gif")));
            btnStart.setBounds(241, 179, 141, 65);
            contentPane.add(btnStart);
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Deatiled StackTrace is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at MathJFrame$4.actionPerformed(MathJFrame.java:105)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What's the error message? Please provide the stack trace.

Comment: StackTrace Please.............

Comment: Why are you catching Runtime Exception as the most outer catch statement?

Comment: The stack trace is up there. I don't know why I'm catching it there, im kinda new at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add line

```
userAnswer = Integer.parseInt(answer);
```

inside your try-catch statement every time you are taking the input .

```
                try {
                    userAnswer = Integer.parseInt(answer);//Add this line here 
                    if (userAnswer == 5) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good!!");
                        score = score + awarded;
                    }

                    else {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "Not Even Close!");
                    }
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("enter a number");
                }
```

Repeat above for all such occurrences in your code.

Comment: Thank you sooooooo much. I can go to sleep now! :)

Comment: But still the Integer.parseInt statement is embedded within the outer try block. He just needs to add S.O.P in the outermost catch block.

Comment: How is it any different from printing the stack trace. Anyway catching NumberFormatException is just a special case. One must not not catch Runtime Exceptions unless you intent to do something with it.